# Возможность копирования содержимого столбцов NSTableView в Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

Не могу скопировать информацию которая приходит в сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связал с функцией, но столбцы не активные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@IBAction func onEnterInTextField(_ sender: NSTextFieldCell) {
    let selectedRowNumber = messagesTable.selectedRow
    if selectedRowNumber != -1 {
        items[selectedRowNumber] = sender.stringValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблица становится активная при клике и так же редактируемая если использовать функцию со значение true.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
     return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать метод делегата NSTableView:

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    let selectedRowNumber = messagesTable.selectedRow
    //
}
```